# Layout Inspector not working on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am getting the following error when trying to use Android Studio Layout inspector to debug my composables

```
Could not download androidx.compose.ui:ui:writeVersionFile .... (See a picture)
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Addition Info

- Mac M1 Chip
- Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Beta 2
- Internet: OK

Comment: In my case the issue was caused by `androidx.tv:tv-foundation:1.0.0-alpha07` and `androidx.tv:tv-material:1.0.0-alpha07` no solution yet unless if don't use android tv compose.

Answer (score 0):

- Add the mavenCentral() repository in your project's build.gradle

file:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

Reload your project and update Gradle dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.3")
}

android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.2"
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

You can find more information at this link

[https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue here. The kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.4.2 isn't released. The latest version is 1.4.1-dev-k1.8.10-c312d77f4cb.

Comment: What do you mean it is not released?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, on my case I down grade the Material 3 version from `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha02` to `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha01`
I am using the material library too `androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.3`. I hope this could help, if not, you should search which library is blocking the Layout Inspector.